# java regular expression finding bullet lists

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to match any bullet list in a free text document.   Bullet lists are defined as any number or lowercase character preceeded by a word delimiter.   So for example

```
1.  item a
2.  item b
```

I use the following code to find the bullets:

```
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("\\s[\\d][\\.\\)]\\s");
```

This works well as long as the bullet list consist of single digit items.   However, as soon as I try multiple digit bullet lists, it won't work (example `12. item c 13. item d`)    I tried altering the the pattern to

```
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("\\s[\\d]+[\\.\\)]\\s");
```

or

```
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("\\s[\\d]\\+[\\.\\)]\\s");
```

My interpretation of the regex language is that this would match any case where there are 1 or more digits preceding a ".".    But this doesn't work.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Btw, could you define `But this doesn't work.`?

Comment: That's a strange definition of 'bullet list'. What it really means is a list whose items are introduced by 'bullet' characters. What you are looking for is items in lettered or numbered lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("\\s[\\d]+[\\.\\)]\\s");
```

(your second version) should work, but you can simplify it:

```
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("\\s\\d+[.)]\\s");
```

However, it does expect whitespace before the digit (so it won't match at the start of the string, for example). Perhaps a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) is useful here:

```
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("\\b\\d+[.)]\\s");
```

(FYI: Your third example was trying to match a literal `+` after a single digit. That's why it failed).

Answer (score 1):

a more simple regex (not tested) :

```
\\s(\\d+)[.)]\\s
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the problem is that there's not always whitespace in front of the digits. Thus change the expression to (Java string version) `"\\s*\\d+[\\.\\)]\\s"`.

Example:

```
10. aaa //no whitespace before 10 here, thus the leading whitespace has to be optional
11. bbb //here the whitespace should match the new line which counts as whitespace
```

As for the lower case character version:

```
"\\s*(?:\\d+|[a-z]+)[\\.\\)]\\s"
```

where `(?:\\d+|[a-z]+)` means "a sequence of either digits or lower case characters.

Note that this would still match `123a.` even though only the `a.` part would be matched. To allow only bullet points in a line, add `"(?:^|\\n)"` (Java string again) at the beginning of the expression, which means the match must either start at the beginning of the text or after a line break.

Comment: In this example, the `\s` would have matched the newline before `10`.